# removeAttr() is removing properties from children

Tags: jquery

I just want to target a specific id like this and remove the link:

```
jQuery("li.menu-item-3741 a").removeAttr("href");
```

but it is also removing links from a ul underneath! So all menu items have no link.

So this:

```
<li id="menu-item-3741" class="x-megamenu col-3 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3741">
    <a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/geography/">
        <span>Geography</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3759">
            <a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/salesandmarketing/business-development/agents/">
                <span>Agents</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4136">
                    <a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/salesandmarketing/business-development/agents/">
                        <span>Agent Finder</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Turns into this: (all links removed)

```
<li id="menu-item-3741" class="x-megamenu col-3 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3741">
    <a><span>Geography</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3759">
            <a><span>Agents</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4136">
                    <a><span>Agent Finder</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq and select first element

```
jQuery("li.menu-item-3741 a").eq(0).removeAttr("href");
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpo6pzgr/

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you're targeting children `a` elements only. Please note that `menu-item-3741` is an id so the selector should be `#menu-item-3741` and given the uniqueness of IDs, you do not to use `li` in front of the selector.

```
jQuery('#menu-item-3741 > a').removeAttr('href');
```

Or:

```
jQuery('#menu-item-3741').children('a').removeAttr('href');
```

```js
$('#menu-item-3741 > a').removeAttr('href');
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <li id="menu-item-3741" class="x-megamenu col-3 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3741"><a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/geography/"><span>Geography</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3759"><a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/salesandmarketing/business-development/agents/"><span>Agents</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4136"><a href="http://jsicentral.com/jsi/salesandmarketing/business-development/agents/"><span>Agent Finder</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector selects all `<a>` elements that are [*descendants*](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) of the `<li>` element.  In your HTML (which is missing several close tags), all of the elements are descendants of `li.menu-item-3741`.

Do you want only immediate children?  Then use [`>`](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):  `$('li.menu-item-3741 > a')`.

Note too that although you mentioned 'id' in your question, you are using a [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (`.`) rather than an [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (`#`).